# software for sorting algorithms animation

Tags: animation

I am planning on working on an interactive application that graphically animates the various sorting algorithms in action. Most of the examples of this kind on the web seems to be using java applets. I was wondering what other software/tools would be well suited to develop an application like this. It may or may not be web-based. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Dinesh

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this? http://sorting-algorithms.com I guess flash would be an obvious candidate, but is bulky. That website uses gifs! I personally like it

Comment: I was looking for something more like this: http://www.iste.uni-stuttgart.de/ps/Ploedereder/sorter/sortanimation2.html

Comment: That's not javascript, that's a java applet written in java. I really hate those, personally, because they tend to be slow and poorly written... I'd advise flash if you're thinking of something like that. ActionScript is pretty easy to learn and fast to setup.

Answer (score 0):

Flash and Silverlight are well-suited for showing such showing animations. It's should be easier to create a nice animation than with Java.

Answer (score 0):

With recent advancements in client-side web application development technologies, it's pretty easy to make something like that using Javascript and HTML5 features like `<canvas>`, that most of the browsers already implement. Even if they don't, there are fallback mechanisms, like [explorercanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) aimed at Internet Explorer browsers.

And because it takes a simple option of "view source", the code behind the animations is much more accessible than Flash or Java, which would require to provide the source code separately.

Answer (score 0):

[Done](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/).

2nd result for Google: `sorting algorithms`